# SimplesamlPHP infinite redirection

Tags: php, saml, simplesamlphp

I'd setup `simplesamlphp` to my localhost as a 3 different virtual host.

```
1. http://idp-saml.com
2. http://sp-saml.com
3. http://api-saml.com
```

When I tried to connect `idp-saml.com` using `sp-saml.com` then it works fine.

Now, I want to integrate it with my own application `api-saml.com`.

For that, I'd follow the below steps:

1. Create "authsouce" to `sp-saml.com` on 'authsources.php'.

   `'sp1' => array(
           'saml:SP',
           'privatekey' => 'sp-saml.pem',
           'certificate' => 'sp-saml.crt',
           'entityID' => 'http://api-saml.com',
           'idp' => 'http://idp-saml.com',
       )`
2. Now, go to the `Federation` page and click on "SP1" metadata and copy `SAML 2.0 Metadata XML`
3. Then go to `idp-saml.com` and open `metadata-converter.php` and parse `SAML 2.0 Metadata XML`.
4. Copy both `shib13-sp-remote` and `saml20-sp-remote` to `metadata\shib13-sp-remote.php` and `metadata\saml20-sp-remote.php` on `idp-saml.com` virtual host and I can see `api-saml.com` under `federation` tab under `SAML 2.0 SP Metadata (Trusted)` section.

https://www.screencast.com/t/424rmDxRlRfV

5. Now, Go to `api-saml.com` directory and create `index.php` and add below code

`require_once('sp-saml/lib/_autoload.php');`

```
$saml_auth = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('sp1');

if ($saml_auth->isAuthenticated()) {
    $attributes = $saml_auth->getAttributes();    
    var_dump($attributes);    
}
else {
    $saml_auth->requireAuth();
}
```

6. Now, tried to access `http://api-saml.com` and it goes to `idp-saml.com` and ask me for login credentials. After adding credentials it does not redirect back me to `api-saml.com` and behave like infinite redirection. You can see https://www.screencast.com/t/VGhDHE1j

Answer (score 1):

You app and the authsource SP metadata should be on the same domain. Your steps 1 and 2 should download the metadata from `http://api-saml.com/simplesaml/...` rather than from a domain that is distinct from your app.

The SP metadata contains information on authorized `Assertion Consumer Service` (ACS) urls - and the metadata you are generating and then loading into the IdP only lists paths under http://sp-saml.com as a legitimate return urls. When you attempt to use the authsource from a different domain then the IdP see an unauthorized return url, ignores it and instead uses the one from the metadata which isn't want you want.

Comment: I agree with you but now I want to create 2 more subdomain `beta.api-saml.com` & `alpha.api-saml.com` on same server then what I will do? Do I need to install `simplesaml` on both sub domain OR is there any other way?